# Quadratic programming and Lagrange multiplier in SVM

Tags: machine-learning, svm

I am a little confused because for some simple functions and constraints, using the Lagrange multiplier will be able to solve for the variables. However, in the SVM Lagrange expression, I learned that we had to use quadratic programming to solve for the maximum AFTER we express it in terms of Lagrange expression with some constraints:
[image]

Does that mean this problem can't be solved only using the Lagrange method? I'm not familiar with **quadratic programming or the Lagrange multiplier.** Could someone please kindly explain the relationship between the two? Preferably in the context of Support Vector Machines. Thank you so much!